# ui:inputCheckbox disabled property not working in Microsoft edge

Tags: lightning, lightning-experience, lightning-design-system, html5, javascript-controller

I am dynamically rendering disabled property of checkbox to true or false from controller. This works fine for other browsers but does not for Microsoft Edge. The checkbox remains disabled, i.e it is not clickable, but it's style is that of enabled.

```
<aura:iteration items="{!v.recordsList}" var="record" indexVar="index">

    <tr class="slds-hint-parent slds-line-height--reset" style = "line-height : 1.2rem">
        <td >
            <div class="{!or(record.isChecked) ? 'slds-hide' : 'slds-checkbox--add-button slds-m-left--small'}">                                    
                <ui:inputCheckbox value="{!record.isChecked}" class="slds-assistive-text" disabled="{!!record.isDefinitelyEligible}" />
                <label id='{!record.Identity}' value='{!record}' class="{!'slds-checkbox--faux ' +record.Id}" data-rec = "{!record}" onclick="{!c.updateSelection}">
                </label>
            </div>
        </td>
<!-- SOME CODE -->
```

From Controller , I make `isDefinitelyEligible= false`, hence the checkbox turns to disabled. This works in Chrome but not in Microsoft edge. What could be the reason?